# how to create list from data json on javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

i have data json like this:

```
{
   a: {
      content: "value A"
   },
   b: {
      content: "value B",
      c: {
         content: "value C"
      }
   }
}
```

and I want to display it into a list like this:

- value A
- value B

  - value C

Please help me, thanks

Comment: Did you attempt anything? It is a recursive loop. just an FYI: order is not guaranteed with Objects.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question lacks any attempt at solving this problem on your own. The idea is for you to try to get something to work and then come here with specific problems you are unable to resolve. Taking the tour and reading about [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center will provide all the information you need.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would implement a function which traverses the object and generates ul-li content.

```js
var input = {
   a: {
      content: "value A"
   },
   b: {
      content: "value B",
      c: {
         content: "value C"
      }
   }
};

function getStructure(input) {
    var children = "";
    for (let key in input) {
        if (key === "content") {
            children += `<li>${input[key]}</li>`;
        } else {
            children += `<ul>${getStructure(input[key])}</ul>`;
        }
    }
    return `<ul>${children}</ul>`;
}

document.body.innerHTML += (getStructure(input));
```

Comment: My answer contains a solution that, according to the snippet works. I do not know why it is downvoted.

Comment: hai, sorry but this solved